# Unstaging changed file from commit in PR

Tags: git, file, version-control

I'm definitely overcomplicating this, but I am wondering how to "unstage" the changes that were made to a few files inadvertently in a commit in a pull request. Without making a mess in Git.

Basically there were some files in a `/dist` folder that were slightly changed on accident after the application compiled.

The catch is I am trying to avoid making extra commits or having to squash my commits, if possible. Can this be done with `git commit --amend`?

Comment: I assume you've pushed your files to a remote? Then don't ammend. It will cause huge headaches. If you've pushed to remote, your best option is to make a new commit. If your team judges you for making a mistake in a PR, then find a new team.

Comment: @NickBailey valid point. However I meant to say that there is already a `/dist` folder with files up on the remote, and I wanted to find a way to unstage the changes made to those files (in the PR) without just copying the raw contents of the current files and pasting those into a new commit. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have changed the files in PR, and have them currently staged, and don't want to further alter the files in `/dist` on remote, simply unstage everything on PR (`git reset`), then re-stage all but files in `/dist` (on PR), and then wipe the local changes to the files in `/dist`:

```
git clean -df
git checkout -- .
```

This won't touch the staged/committed files.

But somehow I have a feeling what you're trying to do is not this uncomplicated.. If you want to revert the files in remote `/dist`, then it's best to do another commit, perhaps with `revert` (or if you can afford to rewrite the remote repo history, i.e. you know for sure others haven't pulled a copy, or can/want to communicate it to the rest of the team, then check out the history-altering approach to undoing the change in [my recent other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37036587/134536)).